# Class Hierarchy with down cast function pointers

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pointer-to-member, virtual-inheritance, incompatibletypeerror

**TL;DR** How can I get the `Base::Choose` to accept `Derived::CustomUserFunction` as an argument?
The error I'm getting, and I do understand why I get it, but I don't know how to resolve it is:
`Argument of type "Derived::* (...)" is incompatible with parameter of type "Base::* (...)"`

```
#include <iostream>
    class Base {
    public:
        void Base::Choose(void(Base::*FctPtr)()) {
            (this->*FctPtr)();
        }

        virtual void Base::CustomUserFunction() = 0;
};

    class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void Derived::CustomUserFunction() {
            std::cout << "CustomFunction\n";
        }
 };

    int main()  {
        Derived D;
        D.Choose(&D.CustomUserFunction);
    }
```

**Full version**

I'm writing a Discreet Event Simulation Engine (DESEngine) that uses custom User Functions. Since these Custom User Functions are **problem specific**, I want to be able to call them **without knowing their signature name.** The engine reads `TURN_ON` in a text file and looks for the function pointer mapped to the `TURN_ON` string alias in an unordered_map.

Basically DESEngine would call upon `UserEvents::Choose(std::string Name)` that would call a function given by it's event name (string).

Everything was working great, but **manageability is getting tough** since I have to use the engine for lots of different problems (from differential equation solving to simulating simple computers). *(And I had all sorts of different problem specific functions inside my UserEvents class)*

Because of that, I've decided to make my class `UserEvents` an abstract class and **inherit it for each kind of problem I have, thus, custom user functions would be stored in the derived class**, not in the base, but I want the `"Choose"` method to reside in the base class. *How can I call the functions within the derived classes from the base class?*

The error I'm getting, and I do understand why I get it, but I don't know how to resolve it is:
`Argument of type "UserEvents_MVN::* (...)" is incompatible with parameter of type "UserEvents::* (...)"`

```
class UserEvents
{   
    public:
    // Receives an event name and parameters
    struct EventWithParams { std::string Name; std::vector<boost::any> Params; };

    // Lets an outside class (DESEngine) configure which event to run before calling UserEvents::Choose()
    // TODO: Make getters/setters so Events can be passed through a better way
        EventWithParams Event;

        // Select which function(parameters) to call based on the EventWithParams Event (above)
        int UserEvents::Choose();

    protected:
        void UserEvents::UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction
        (std::string Alias, void(UserEvents::*FunctionPointer)(const std::vector<boost::any>&));

        virtual void UserEvents::BuildUFPAliasMap() = 0;

    private:

        // Here we have an unordered map that assigns User Function (pointer) to each Key (string or Alias or Event Name)
        std::unordered_map<std::string, void(UserEvents::*)(const std::vector<boost::any>&)> UserFunctionPointerAliasMap;
    };
```

Here's the implementation of Choose

```
int UserEvents::Choose()
    {
        try
        {
            (this->*UserFunctionPointerAliasMap.at(Event.Name))(Event.Params);
            return 0;
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range e)
        {
            throw std::exception::exception("Unknown User Event");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

An example of a derived class

```
#pragma once
#include "..\\UserEvents.h"

class UserEvents_MVN : public UserEvents
{
public:
    UserEvents_MVN();
    ~UserEvents_MVN();

protected:

    void UserEvents_MVN::MEMDUMP_LOAD(const std::vector<boost::any> &Parameters);

    void UserEvents_MVN::MEMDUMP(const std::vector<boost::any> &Parameters);

    void UserEvents_MVN::InstructionDecode(const std::vector<boost::any> &Parameters);


private:

    virtual void UserEvents_MVN::BuildUFPAliasMap();
};
```

And how I build the index of function pointers (UserFunctionPointerAliasMap)

```
void UserEvents_MVN::BuildUFPAliasMap()
{
    UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction("MEMDUMP_LOAD",  &UserEvents_MVN::MEMDUMP_LOAD );
    UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction("MEMDUMP",   &UserEvents_MVN::MEMDUMP );
    UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction("DECODE",    &UserEvents_MVN::InstructionDecode);
}
```

Comment: What? You are trying to store pointers as pointers to members of `UserEvents`, but those functions are not members of that class.

Comment: @BoPersson you are correct. I want the base class to handle the unordered_map that stores the function pointers but I want them to be of functions of it's derived classes. How can I work around this?

Comment: Would be great to know why it was down voted so I could do better next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sought out help in IRC to which someone pointed me to [CRTP - Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which allows methods within Base to access members of Derived and that is what I aim for.

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template<class T>
class Base
{
    // methods within Base can use template to access members of Derived
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

And they kindly sent me an [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BQvGWaz89ksJ021v)

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Dispatch
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, void (T::*)()> commands;

    protected: // used by application type only
    void Add(std::string name, void (T::*fptr)())
    {
        commands[name] = fptr;
    }

    public: // becomes part of the public interface for application type
    /* This part is the only reason to use CRTP/inheritance. The application
       type could simply create this method itself and just call functions of
       a Dispatch<App> member to do all the work, but this approach saves us
       from typing that out. */
    void Choose(std::string s)
    {
        auto fptr = commands.at(s);
        auto target = static_cast<T*>(this);
        (target->*fptr)();
    }
};

class App : public Dispatch<App>
{
public:
    App()
    {
        // for demo purposes
        Add("foo", &App::Test);
    }

    void Test()
    {
        std::cout << "dispatched!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    App a;
    a.Choose("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve the problem is define `virtual` member functions in `UserEvents` and use them in building the map.

Example:

```
class UserEvents
{   
  public:

    virtual void MEMDUMP_LOAD(const std::vector<boost::any> &Parameters) = 0;

 ...
};
```

and then override the `virtual` functin in `UserEvents_MVN`.

```
class UserEvents_MVN : public UserEvents
{
  public:
    UserEvents_MVN();
    ~UserEvents_MVN();

  protected:

    void MEMDUMP_LOAD(const std::vector<boost::any> &Parameters) override;

  ...
};
```

and build the map using:

```
void UserEvents_MVN::BuildUFPAliasMap()
{
    UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction("MEMDUMP_LOAD",  &UserEvents::MEMDUMP_LOAD );
    ...
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

The other option is to use `std::function` in the map.

Let's say your `map` is defined as:

```
using FunctionMap = std::map<std::string, std::function<void(UserEvent*, std::vector<boost::any>&)>>;
FunctionMap myFunctionMap;
```

Then, you can use `lambda` functions to flesh out `myFunctionMap`.

```
void UserEvents_MVN::BuildUFPAliasMap()
{
    UserFunctionPointerMap_AddFunction("MEMDUMP_LOAD",
                                        [](UserEvent* event, std::vector<boost::any>& parameters))
                                        { dynamic_cast<UserEvents_MVN*>(event)->MEMDUMP_LOAD(parameters);});
    ...
}
```

Comment: But that would invalidate the reason why I made the class abstract. Since `UserEvents` can represent MANY different custom user events (It could be to simulate a simple computer or a differential equation solver or a city traffic system or ...) I want it as general as possible, leaving problem specific functions for the derived classes.